# MAMP not working: "This site can't be reached"

Tags: wordpress, apache, server, mamp

I've been trying to port a standalone website I've been working on to WordPress. However, I haven't been able to install WordPress locally because MAMP isn't working properly.

I've installed MAMP on my computer fine. However, when I start the server and press "Open WebStart page", my default browser tells me "This site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect." I also noticed that there is only one green dot by MySQL Server; both the Apache Server and Cloud have white dots next to them.

I've tried a couple things with no luck. I've restarted my computer, but the same problem persisted. I went into MAMP Preferences and reset the ports to the default (8888 for Apache, 7888 for Nginx and 8889 for MySQL) but that had no effect. I've tried switching to Nginx, but kept getting 504 errors. Lastly, I've tried accessing the WebStart page in multiple different browsers with no luck, as well.

I'm running this on Windows 10 Professional.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you're probably trying to hit http[s]://localhost instead of http[s]://localhost:8888 ... your Apache port is set to 8888 so you need to tell the browser to look to that port. If you want to use the standard ports, you'd go to the "ports" section in MAMP and click the "Set server ports to 80, 81, 443, 7443, 3306, and 11211" option (or the equivalent). There's also the "Set server to MAMP ports" which moves all the ports back to 8888, 7888, 8890, etc.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this answer actually explains the _why_ instead of just providing the _how_

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, here's the fix that worked for me.

Launch **MAMP** stop the server then at the toolbar at the top press on MAMP-> ports then press set ports to default and then restart the servers it should work fine then.

Answer (score 1):

Click on MAMP drop down, and click on preferences.
Then go to PHP.

Click on the Standard version drop down; and change it from 7.3.7 to 7.2.14.

Click OK.

Everything should be working fine now.